# Making Jasmine list all tests instead of executing them

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am using Jasmine for unit testing. By now the tests are running rather long. Of course I can specify suitable URL parameters to pick the desired tests. However I would find it way more convenient if I could tell Jasmine to only list all tests and then execute whatever I explicitly pick. Has anyone an idea how to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I found it out on my own. Maybe others know a better solution but I can achieve the desired effect by passing the Jasmine TestRunner the parameters `package` and `spec` with package pointing to my root package and spec pointing to a non existing spec. This makes the test runner skip all packages. Then I can checkmark "skipped" and immediately get a list of all skipped tests which is of course a link list for all tests.

This almost solves my issue. Except that I would still need a way to tell it to check the checkbox for me.